# React Ant Design type input value not clear

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im using my react project to [Ant design](https://3x.ant.design/components/drawer/), I faced some conflict on the forms , When i fill the forms and get close the drawer but next time i again open drawer at this time filling values not clear , any one know any solution for this ?

**[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zk931d)**

**Code here**

```
const { Option } = Select;

class DrawerForm extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false };

  showDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  onClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showDrawer}>
          <Icon type="plus" /> New account
        </Button>
        <Drawer
          title="Create a new account"
          width={720}
          onClose={this.onClose}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
        >
          <Form layout="vertical" hideRequiredMark>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="Name">
                  {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter user name' }],
                  })(<Input placeholder="Please enter user name" />)}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="Url">
                  {getFieldDecorator('url', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter url' }],
                  })(
                    <Input
                      style={{ width: '100%' }}
                      addonBefore="http://"
                      addonAfter=".com"
                      placeholder="Please enter url"
                    />,
                  )}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="Owner">
                  {getFieldDecorator('owner', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select an owner' }],
                  })(
                    <Select placeholder="Please select an owner">
                      <Option value="xiao">Xiaoxiao Fu</Option>
                      <Option value="mao">Maomao Zhou</Option>
                    </Select>,
                  )}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="Type">
                  {getFieldDecorator('type', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please choose the type' }],
                  })(
                    <Select placeholder="Please choose the type">
                      <Option value="private">Private</Option>
                      <Option value="public">Public</Option>
                    </Select>,
                  )}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="Approver">
                  {getFieldDecorator('approver', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please choose the approver' }],
                  })(
                    <Select placeholder="Please choose the approver">
                      <Option value="jack">Jack Ma</Option>
                      <Option value="tom">Tom Liu</Option>
                    </Select>,
                  )}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label="DateTime">
                  {getFieldDecorator('dateTime', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please choose the dateTime' }],
                  })(
                    <DatePicker.RangePicker
                      style={{ width: '100%' }}
                      getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentNode}
                    />,
                  )}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={24}>
                <Form.Item label="Description">
                  {getFieldDecorator('description', {
                    rules: [
                      {
                        required: true,
                        message: 'please enter url description',
                      },
                    ],
                  })(<Input.TextArea rows={4} placeholder="please enter url description" />)}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
          <div
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              width: '100%',
              borderTop: '1px solid #e9e9e9',
              padding: '10px 16px',
              background: '#fff',
              textAlign: 'right',
            }}
          >
            <Button onClick={this.onClose} style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.onClose} type="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you using your inputs' values ?

Comment: @Incepter hello,  I get the same form

Comment: Yes I know, I mean, What are you doing with the for ? because i did now saw any state collecting its values

Comment: @Incepter hello, can you please go to the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zk931d, and fill some data. next close the drawer and again click the new account button, you can see the you're filling data not clear , that is a my issue

Comment: Yes it is predicted from the code. Now, to provide you a proper solution, I need to know what are you using the form data for ? do you send it via api ? Because the submit button only closes the modal. One naive solution is to add a state directly in your component and simply empty its values when the dialog is closed

Comment: Hello ,Yes,i have a two form dynamically form and normal form, , one form using Jason data, do you have idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `form.resetFields()` on close your form. So it'll automatically clear entered data

**EDIT**
Try to use this code, it should work

```
  onClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
    this.props.form.resetFields()
  };
```

Comment: Thank for your solution and time, then I tried , but not working

Comment: @core114, I'm edited answer. Can you check it again. Is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it appeared when use `extra` property in `Input`. I should resolve it.